# Why does npm install many packages into "/node_modules" instead of only one?

Tags: node.js, npm

I experience strange behavior of `npm` on `npm install <package>` command. Before it installed a package in its own dedicated directory. For example, I type this command:

```
$ npm i babel-preset-es2015
```

And I get only one `/babel-preset-es2015` directory under `/node_modules` directory, like this:

```
node_modules/babel-preset-es2015
```

Now it populates my `/node_modules` with dozen strange packages. On `babel-preset-es2015` installation it installs some 94 packages:

[image]

What a behavior is this? Is it normal? Why does it start happening? Is it some king of settings I activeted by mistake? My npm and node versions:

```
$ npm -v
3.3.12
$ node -v
v5.3.0
```

Comment: i'm guessing `babel-preset-es201` has its own `npm` module dependencies that need get installed as well.

Comment: @ptierno, of course it has. Every package has them. But it wasn't so before. Only one directory was created.

Answer (score 6):

because you are using npm v3 which installs dependencies flattened, so dependencies of dependencies (and their dependencies ...) end up in same folder,
more on [npm v3 changelog](https://github.com/npm/npm/releases/tag/v3.0.0)